# Nginx чпу - убрать цифры в конце URL

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, php-nginx

Добрый день!
Помогите пожалуйста прописать правило в `location` для `nginx`, чтобы убрать цифры из url такого вида: `/article/integraciya-ip-telefonii-v-crm-sistemy/20`, чтобы было просто `/article/integraciya-ip-telefonii-v-crm-sistemy/`

Answer (score 0):

rewrite ^(/article/integraciya-ip-telefonii-v-crm-sistemy/)[0-9]+$ $1 ; не работает?